# Chown and chmod in ubuntu with different applications using common files

Tags: 18.04, chmod, chown

I'm having problems with chown and chmod in ubuntu 18.04.
When I use `php + nginx`: 
`touch ('/var/www/a.log');`
`user:own` of `a.log` is `nginx:nginx` and chmod is `rw-r-r--`
when i use

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i' b.mp3 >a.log 2>&1');
```

The above command was not able to run because it `does not have access to the a.log file`, it seems that ffmpeg was running under user `ive` (this is my ubuntu login account). It could not write to the log file. I hope you will give me advice to handle this case. I am using ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.
p:s I was thinking of a root login solution so that all commands run with root but not yet. When logged in with root at the ubuntu login screen. Although I have entered the correct password, it still gives me the wrong password. :(

Comment: What is the owner of those log files?

Comment: Hi Tung Tran, owner of the file is nginx

Comment: do you mean user `www-data`?

Comment: No, in the nginx configuration I use `user nginx;`

Comment: Could you please add the output of `ls -la /var/www/`?

Comment: Here is it: https://i.imgur.com/8r1L4Vr.png, thank u :D

Comment: I suppose you'd better change mode of `/var/www/*.log` to `664` (it won't be risky to allow group having write permission) and add your user `ive` into the group nginx `sudo usermod nginx ive`

Comment: I did that but still did not. The problem is that when I create the .log file with `touch ()` of php, the `owner` of it is `nginx`, and only nginx has the right to read/write this file. When i use command `shell_exec('ffmpeg ... >my.log 2>&1 ')` then `ffmpeg does not have the right to write stderr to the log file` because it is not authorized. The ownership of the .log file when `created with touch () is read only`. You know what I mean. :(

Comment: Did you try function `chmod("/var/log/yourlog.log", 664);` after `touch();`?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. So I will add the solution into an answer so that any other users having the same issue will be resolved. Otherwise, if possible, please kindly mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

At first, add your user into nginx group:

```
sudo usermod -G nginx ive
```

And then add this line after your `touch();` function:

```
chmod("/var/log/yourlog.log", 664);
```

Comment: Should be `usermod`, also `usermod -G` will remove the user from any other groups, that's normally not what one want.

Comment: You’re right. Macos’s correction did so.

Answer (score -1):

Use [groups](https://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu) for what you are trying to do.
You can't use root to login because as stated [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

> By default, the root account password is locked in Ubuntu.

The password you used in `sudo` is not the password in root.

Comment: Thank you. However, I used the `sudo passwd root` command to change the password of the root account as instructed on youtube. It still does not work when I try to log in as root

Comment: In that case, `sudo -i` at your user first to interactive root followed by `passwd` to change it will enable the root account.